# What causes commands to print on first line in Terminal.app on Mac OS X 10.8?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, osx-mountain-lion, terminal.app

Every time I execute a command in Terminal.app, the command prints in the beginning of the first output line like this:

```
> ls 
lsfile1 file2 file3
```

This only happens in Terminal.app, iTerm.app for example does not do this.

What causes this? How can I fix it?

---

My `.zshrc`

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export TERM=screen-256color
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:usr/local/sbin
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/johan/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH
plugins=(git npm node github brew nyan)
```

Comment: Can you show the full text of what you see when you open a new terminal window, up to and including the prompt? Are you comfortable doing something like `nano ~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: I see `➜  ~  `. Yeah I'm comfortable doing that - but prefer `vi` :). I probably should've mentioned I'm using ZSH. The behaviour still differs between Terminal.app and iTerm.app though. I tried switching to `bash` in Terminal.app - the problem does NOT exist with `bash`. I can't find anything odd in my `.zshrc`.

Comment: If you are comfortable doing it, you should probably post your .zshrc file in your question,  and maybe the output of `set`. Did you select zsh in the terminal prefs or via `chsh`?

Comment: Did the first, `set` output is huge though so I'd prefer not to post it. What might I be looking for in there. I used `chsh`.

Answer (score 0):

What does `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND` or `trap` return?

Check your shell configuration files:

```
cat ~/.bash_profile ~/.profile ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_login /etc/profile /etc/bashrc
```

Are both Terminal (in the Startup tab) and iTerm (in Profiles > your profile > General > Command) set to open new shells with the default login shell?

Comment: The commands return: 
`➜  ~  echo $PROMPT_COMMAND` `echo`
`➜  ~  trap` `trap%`
Both are set to open with default login shell, for me being `zsh`.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen sometimes if you've resized the Terminal window.  That might be the answer to your first question; but, if you're seeing this for every command, even after opening a new Terminal window and not resizing it, it's unlikely to be related.  (with a disclaimer that if it could also be related to the full-screen behavior in Mountain Lion)

And, I don't know about the second part.  None of <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>, `clear`, or `reset` ever seem to work for me when I encounter similar issues.

Comment: I get it for all commands, in new windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=163822), and this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086091/tmux-disable-echo-of-last-run-command), it is due to xterm settings being passed by oh-my-zsh or one of its themes. The solutions varied, so you will have to try both. Maybe the `.tmux.conf` one first?